# How to prevent indexing of non-academic content by Google Scholar?

Tags: meta-tags, noindex, google-scholar

I work at a research institutions that has a Wordpress website where we publish academic articles and other content such as events, awards, news updates etc.

We want to use the plugin [Kblog Metadata](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kblog-metadata/) in order for Google Scholar to crawl and correctly index our academic content.

We also want to **prevent non-academic content from being indexed by Google Scholar** while allowing the "normal" google crawler to crawl and index those pages.

Do you know of a meta-tag that Google Scholar recognizes as noindex?

Or, alternatively, do you have another idea on how to achieve this goal?

I read the [Google Scholar Guidelines for Webmasters](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) and didn't find any information about this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google Scholar doesn't have own bot, so you can't block it without to block indexing of the whole site.

But i think you shouldn't worry about the subject. Google Scholar tends to index less then more. I mean, to move GoogleScholar to index some of your (academic) content, you will be forced to prove stringently that your content is worth to be published.

One of the first meaningful actions is to implement Dublin Core meta-tags, like under https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing. One this way you give Google Scholar a signal - content with these special meta-tags is a candidate to be published at.

By implication, content *without* Dublin Core meta-tags will be recognized as non-academic and be indexed as *usual* content by *usual* Google, but not as academic by Google Scholar.